# Forcing all traffic through OpenVPN from the client on Windows XP

Tags: networking, windows-xp, routing, openvpn

Is there any way that a client can decide, on it's own, whether to route all traffic through OpenVPN or not?

I know that I can add:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

to my server config, but sometimes I'd like to decide on the client whether or not to use this. I suppose I could create two profiles, but that seems like a lot of overhead.

I suppose this may be more of a Windows question than OpenVPN; how can I easily set up a default route?

[Obviously, my server is set up to handle IP forwarding; I have one client that always uses `redirect-gateway def1`. I'm asking specifically about the other clients]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "route-nopull" option on clients that do not want to force all traffic into the VPN.

Comment: But this would require me to modify the server config, right? I want to have the ability to have the client choose.

Comment: nope, you put that option in the client config